# nested *ngFor with "keys" pipe iterates but doesn't bind data

Tags: angular, typescript, angularfire2, ngfor

I use `Firebase` and `AngularFire2` with my app so the nested arrays are by default objects which fixes fine with the famous `keys` pipe.  It iterates the right number of instances but doesn't attach any of the data to anything.  The `console.log()` I have shows all the data has made it so I don't understand what the problem is.

Here's the exported chunk of data from `Firebase`

```
{
  "01" : {
    "answers" : {
      "01" : {
        "answer" : "Less than 4 months",
        "id" : "bus_info_01_a_01"
      },
      "02" : {
        "answer" : "4 months - 7 months",
        "id" : "bus_info_01_a_02"
      },
      "03" : {
        "answer" : "7 months - 1 year",
        "id" : "bus_info_01_a_03"
      },
      "04" : {
        "answer" : "1-2 years",
        "id" : "bus_info_01_a_04"
      },
      "05" : {
        "answer" : "2-5 years",
        "id" : "bus_info_01_a_05"
      },
      "06" : {
        "answer" : "5-10 years",
        "id" : "bus_info_01_a_06"
      },
      "07" : {
        "answer" : "10+ years",
        "id" : "bus_info_01_a_07"
      }
    },
    "id" : "bus_exp_01",
    "name" : "bus_info_01",
    "question" : "How long have you been in Business?",
    "template" : "multi_choice"
  },
  "02" : {
    "answers" : {
      "01" : {
        "answer" : "yes",
        "id" : "bus_info_02_a_01_01",
        "trigger" : "yes"
      },
      "02" : {
        "answer" : "no",
        "id" : "bus_info_02_a_01_02",
        "trigger" : "no"
      }
    },
    "id" : "bus_exp_02",
    "name" : "bus_info_02",
    "no" : {
      "01" : {
        "id" : "web_no_01",
        "name" : "web_no_q_01",
        "question" : "What type of Industry do you operate in?",
        "template" : "sm_input"
      },
      "02" : {
        "id" : "web_no_02",
        "name" : "web_no_q_02",
        "question" : "What specialty products and or services stand at the forefront of who you are to your Customers?",
        "template" : "sm_input"
      },
      "03" : {
        "id" : "web_no_03",
        "name" : "web_no_q_03",
        "question" : "Would you rather be known for something else despite your current success?",
        "template" : "sm_input"
      },
      "04" : {
        "id" : "web_no_04",
        "name" : "web_no_q_04",
        "question" : "Do you already have a logo?",
        "template" : "sm_input"
      }
    },
    "question" : "Do you have a website?",
    "template" : "multi_choice",
    "yes" : {
      "01" : {
        "id" : "web_yes_01",
        "question" : "Website",
        "template" : "sm_input"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The way I'm calling it into the service is like this

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService implements OnInit{
    MultiChoiceDemo: FirebaseListObservable<any>;

    constructor(private af: AngularFireDatabase){}

    getMulti(){
    this.MultiChoiceDemo = this.af.list('/questionnaire/business_info') 
    as FirebaseListObservable<any>

    return this.MultiChoiceDemo;
    }
}
```

The Component that takes it in is set up like this

```
import { AppService }               from './app.service';



@Component({

    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'questionnaire-page',
    templateUrl:'./questionnaire.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./questionnaire.component.css'],
    providers: [ AppService ]
})



export class QuestionnairePage implements OnInit{

    MultiChoice: FirebaseListObservable<any>;

    constructor(private _data: AppService ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this._data.getMulti().subscribe(MultiChoiceDemo =>{
             this.MultiChoice = MultiChoiceDemo;
             console.log(this.MultiChoice);
         }); 
    }
}
```

It's being loaded into this in the template

```
<fieldset *ngFor="let quest of MultiChoice"  class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-2"></div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8" style="background-color:#777;">
        <label class="col-xs-11 col-sm-7">
            {{quest.question}}
        </label>


        <label *ngFor="let ans of quest.answers | keys" 
            [attr.for]="ans.id" class="col-xs-12">

                <input type="radio" 
                [attr.id]="ans.id"
                [attr.value]="ans.answer"
                [attr.name]="quest.name"
                />
            {{ans.answer}}
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-2 col-md-4"></div>
</fieldset>
```

I've been back and forth adding the `elvis operator` in various places,  I've tried switching the `*ngFor` syntax to

> *ngFor="let ans of (quest.answers | keys)"

there's no errors showing up, the data shows in the `console.log()`, there's an input iterated for each answer, but lookign in the HTML there's nothing but the `name` attribute present on each one which calls to `quest.name`.  Does anybody know why this isn't working?

Comment: how did you implement the keys pipe?

Comment: I imported and added it to the declarations in the `app.module` to make it available to the entire app.

Comment: It would help to see how the pipe code...